# parsing specific date and time order in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in pandas:

[image]

in which:

Date column is in range of 195-730 with 195='01/01/2009',196='01/02/2009' and so on,(type=object not string)

time column is in range of 1-48 for each 30 minutes with 1= 00:00:00 – 00:29:59,(type=object not string)

I'am trying to parse the date and time columns into proper format like this

Date        time

01,01,2009  00:30

```
.          .
.          .
.          .
```

01,01,2009  23:30

01/02/2009  00:30`

I have used the following code for Date colunm but the result is not what I want,any suggestion?

```
`pd.to_datetime(df["Date"],dayfirst='01/01/09', format='%d',errors='ignore')`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a function that takes the values in Date and time columns as integer inputs and converts them to the appropriate python datetime.

```
from datetime import datetime

def convertToDatetime(date_int, time_int):
    timestamp = 1230768000 + (date_int - 195) * 86400 + time_int * 1800
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)

print(convertToDatetime(195, 3))
2009-01-01 01:30:00

print(convertToDatetime(730, 7))
2010-06-20 03:30:00
```

You can use it like this:

```
df['date_proper'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(convertToDatetime(int(row['Date']), int(row['time'])).date()), axis = 1)

df['time_proper'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(convertToDatetime(int(row['Date']), int(row['time'])).time()), axis = 1)
```

Comment: it worked thanks, but it's a bit time consuming since my data set consist of 24465838 record,any advice on making it work faster?!?